# CodeDeploy on EC2 - Missing credentials error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have gone through lot of posts and articles but couldn't solve my problem, hence posting this questions.

I have set of python scripts and wanted to setup CI/CD with Github actions and CodeDeploy so when I push a commit to GitHub, the code is automatically deployed on EC2 instance where I have scheduled the scripts to run using Cron. I have configured Github to integrate with CodeDeploy and no issues there. On CodeDeploy, I created an IAM role `CD_Role` with below policies

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSCodeDeployFullAccess
- AWSCodeDeployRole
- AdministratorAccess

The `AdministratorAccess` I added recently to check if that can solve my problem but no luck. The trust relationship for this role looks like

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I created the EC2 instance, I actually had another role assigned `EC2-Role` and I tried replacing it with `CD_Role` when I wanted to start using CodeDeploy, but the role association was not happening properly, so I modified the `EC2-Role` to have same policies as `CD_Role` and the trust relationship looks like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                    "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Point to note here is that I deploy the CodeDeploy agent at a latter point of configuring EC2 and I tried rebooting the EC2 as well. Listing the instance profile associations gives me,

```
{
    "IamInstanceProfileAssociations": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-XXX", 
            "State": "disassociating", 
            "AssociationId": "iip-assoc-RRR", 
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Id": "XXX", 
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXX:instance-profile/EC2-Role"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-XXX", 
            "State": "associating", 
            "AssociationId": "iip-assoc-XXX", 
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Id": "XXX", 
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXX:instance-profile/CD_Role"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Since both the role have same policies assigned, I would expect the Deployment to work at some stage but I keep getting `ERROR [codedeploy-agent(664)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile`

Can someone please guide to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

add policies

AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).